# Swift 2.2 UITableViewHeaderFooterView transparent

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, uitableviewsectionheader

I'm trying to set a transparent background to a TableViewHeader but without success.
First of all, would like to know if it's possible?

This is what I've done

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
   let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView 
   header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

My final objective is to add under my uitableview an UIView that'll host a GMSMapView and have a transparent HeaderView with a size of 100px.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do following steps

1) in storyboard Add headerfooterview to tableview

2)In view did load write below code

```
tableView.registerClass(HeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView")
headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("headerView") as? HeaderView
```

3) add tableview delegate methods

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 110;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return headerView;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Steps to follow:

1) Drag and drop a UIView from object library to the top of the tableview to make a tableview header.

2)make a IBOutlet of the view in the Tableview controller.

3)lastly call this  UITableview delegate Method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        yourHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return yourHeaderView

    }
```

// this is called when you need to make a transparent footer view

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        return footerView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//for transparent your table view section header:

//In Swift 5

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

view.tintColor = UIColor.clear

}